# passing parameter with space into AWS cli

Tags: json, powershell, aws-cli

I am trying to pass pass parameter with space to `aws cloudformation create-stack` aws cli.

The issue is that my parameter has space. I am using powershell for scripting.

Below is example of my parameter

```
 $JsonParameter = '[{"ParameterKey":"name","ParameterValue":"John"},{"ParameterKey":"Occupation","ParameterValue":"Test Engineer"}]'| ConvertTo-Json
```

This returns

```
"[{\"ParameterKey\":\"name\",\"ParameterValue\":\"John\"},{\"ParameterKey\":\"Occupation\",\"ParameterValue\":\"Test Engineer\"}]"
```

cli command is

```
aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name $stackName --template-url $templateUrl --capabilities $capabilityList --parameters $JsonParameter --region "us-east-1"
```

The error goes

```
Error parsing parameter '--parameters': Invalid JSON:
[{"ParameterKey":"name","ParameterValue":"John"},{"ParameterKey":"Occupation","ParameterValue":"Test
```

From the error, it looks like cli doesn't like the space in the ParameterValue.
How do I escape the space, so that cli doesn't complain about the space in the value?

Comment: Show the full command line that you passed to create-stack.

Comment: I have the same issue, I'm trying to pass an ssh public key...

Comment: See my answer. You immediate problem is the use of `| ConvertTo-Json`. This is solely to convert a Powershell object to Json. Your string is already a json string. You can pass it as is. I included an example where you'd want to use `| ConvertTo-Json`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `| ConvertTo-Json`.

Your string is already a json string so you do not want to perform a conversion.

```
$JsonParameter = '[{"ParameterKey":"name","ParameterValue":"John"},{"ParameterKey":"Occupation","ParameterValue":"Test Engineer"}]'
```

Just use the string as is.

**Alternate scenario**

Should you be working with a Powershell object rather than a json string, you might want at some point to convert it into a json to pass it as parameter to your aws call.

That's the moment where `ConvertTo-Json` would reveal itself to be useful.

Take this for instance

```
$JsonParameter = @(
    @{
        ParameterKey   = 'name'
        ParameterValue = 'John'
    },
    @{
        ParameterKey = 'Occupation'
        ParameterValue = 'Test Engineer'
    }
)
```

This is a Powershell object, for which you might had, in a different context, built from scratch with the intent of passing it as a json paramerter to your aws call.

Now, to achieve the transition from this state of "array of hashtables" to a valid json string, you need to use the `ConvertTo-Json` cmdlet.

```
$JsonParameterString = $JsonParameter | Convertto-json -Compress
```

The resulting string he same as you had initially, ready to be passed down to aws :

```
[{"ParameterKey":"name","ParameterValue":"John"},{"ParameterKey":"Occupation","ParameterValue":"Test Engineer"}]
```

If on the other hand, you had a json string and needed to edit it without fuss, you could use the `ConvertFrom-Json` cmdlet, then edit the resulting object as needed and convert it back to json again before passing it down.

**Additional note**

In my Powershell to Json example,
I used the `-compress` switch parameter. This is optional. This will create a compressed json string (one line) instead of an expanded one.

**Reference**

[Powershell doc - ConvertTo-Json](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-json?view=powershell-7)

Comment: Thank you so much for clarification. -Compress worked